# Insert a scroll bar on my graph CPScatterplot coreplot

Tags: iphone, macos

I am new to coreplot. I would like to insert a horizontal scroll bar on my application in order to move my graph. I don't know how do to this.
I find some code on internet like this:

```
-(IBAction)moveLineLocation:(id)sender {

CPPlotRange *rangeX = plotSpace.xRange;
CPPlotRange *rangeY = plotSpace.yRange; 

rangeX.location = CPDecimalAdd(rangeX.location, CPDecimalFromFloat(-0.5));

plotSpace.xRange = rangeX;
plotSpace.yRange = rangeY;

[graph.axisSet relabelAxes];
[graph reloadData];
}
```

But it's not working. Do you have any hint,idea please

Regards

Comment: The CorePlot framework includes a sample app which demonstrates scrolling, among other features. You really need to read their documentation and look into the sample code, as this is not a simple 'drag-n-drop' framework to use, it's quite complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the Graph scroll without scrollbars:

```
plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
    plotSpace.globalYRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(-5f) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(5)];
    plotSpace.globalXRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(-5f) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(5)];
```

Those ranges are the limits of the scrolling. Make the Y range equal to your graph range to remove scrolling on the Y axis.